# Getting "Call to undefined function yii\caching\ctype_alnum()" error in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2, fatal-error, ampps

I have installed AMPPS on my Mac and its running fine. But when I try to run any project in a browser, I am receiving this error:

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Call to undefined function yii\caching\ctype_alnum()

I have tried to search for this error, to no avail. How can I fix this issue?

I guess this is something related to AMPPS configurations for cache but not able to fix the error.

Comment: I checked everything, i chnaged php version as well but still it had the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. The answer is that i had to switch on the ctype extension in Ampps control panel. On mac, it is necessary to switch on ctype extension to execute project without any error.
Ampps -> Php -> Php Extention -> Ctype